# Scifi novel where God invents the rules of physics as men discovers science, and gets overwhelmed by the complexity of it

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to find this book I read probably something like 15-20 years ago. I can't recall if it was a full book or just a short story in a collection. I think the later. It's also possible I read it in French (can't recall), but maybe it was translated.

God has to come up with explanations as men discover science, creating new rules as he goes (like men are trying to understand what matter is, so he creates atoms, then men probe the atom and he comes up with quarks, etc...). God gets entangled in what is like a complex web of lies where everything must still make sense and work together, and it becomes harder and harder for him to keep track.

Evil influences men so that they try to understand more and more and direct them to the fragile parts of God's design.

At some point near the end, to prevent a nuclear apocalypse, god divides the speed of light in half (because E=mc2) and earth is plunged in darkness for a few minutes, until the light from the sun arrives again.

The story ends with evil winning and God starting over again with "something that has a square orbit". I recall there was a drawing of a square orbit in the book (like earth orbiting the sun, but square).

Comment: If you're cross-posting elsewhere, it's useful to add a link so that people don't keep stumbling over the duplicate post; https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/i5utcv/god_creates_the_rules_of_physics_as_men_discover/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*The Infinite Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinite_Man) by Daniel F. Galouye.

> Between the adoration of the cult, which its leader has increasing
> trouble restraining, and the staff of P&D, psychologically exhausted
> from years of maintaining the P&D fiction against the utter
> destruction of the Universe, the cracks in the cover story develop and
> widen, and the Creative Force arouses and begins to try to simplify
> the Universe in order to make it more manageable - though not
> uninhabitable for its chosen residents; from the original confirmatory
> nova of Proxima Centauri and destruction of Pluto, it deletes all
> quasars observable in the Universe; rationalizes pi at the 323rd
> decimal; halves the speed of light; and changes probability so that
> outcomes bracketing the mean become more likely than the mean itself.
> These revisions to physical reality typically happen after dreams; the
> quasars are seen in Bradford's dreams as "glowflies", as an example;
> and the halving of the speed of light is expressed as "half a sea".
> While these cause some upheaval in everyday life humanity still
> survives on Earth - until the final battle comes between the Creative
> Force, inhabiting Bradford, and the Destructive Force - who had,
> during all this time, been inhabiting and guiding Bradford's
> psychiatrist, Dr. Power, seeking to draw him out, and becoming his
> corporeal adversary in the end.

Comment: Hum.... That might be it, I don't remember some details that I read in this plot but I was a long time ago.